# Manipulate arrays

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I want to sort the array

```
a = {{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0.5, 0.0, 0.5}}, {{-1}, {1}, {-1}}}
```

in the following way: 
`a[[1]]` and `a[[2]]` have one-to-one correspondence; Sort `a[[2]]` from small to great value, at the same time, the sequence of `a[[1]]` will be rearranged accordingly.

In the end, I want to get a new array as

```
{{{1, 0, 0}, {0.5, 0.0, 0.5}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{-1}, {-1}, {1}}}
```

Is there some simple way to realized this in Mathematica?
I appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you seen [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html)?

Comment: Something like this: `Transpose@*SortBy[Last]@*Transpose@a`?

Comment: Just as another option `a = #[[Ordering[Last@a]]] & /@ a`

Comment: You'll need the [stable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304632/stable-sorting-ie-minimally-disruptive-sorting/3332690#3332690) form of `SortBy` to get your output I believe: `SortBy[a\[Transpose], {Last}]\[Transpose]`